# what is the impact of redundant import statements in Java?

Tags: java, performance

What is effected by redundant java `import` statements?

Do they effect the compiled runtime (performance/size)? 
or just stuff like intellisense?

To ask differently:
how important is it to remove them?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments.
This has been very informative.
I am aware of the need to keep my code clean and of when is and when isn't the time to worry about performance.
This was just for added education.
I also feel now that the word "redundant" was the wrong choice here,
what I meant was an import statement that is not needed anymore.
like if you use something like java.util.ArrayList and then change your code in such a way that this class is no longer used.
And I was wandering if the fact that the import statement is still there would make my code larger or slower.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Import statements only affect what happens during compile time.

The compiler takes this code, and creates a `.class` file that represents your code in an executable format (something in binary).

In the end, the binaries are exactly the same, but the method by which they are made are different.

Let's look at a simple case:

```
import java.util.*;
```

vs

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

when used in:

```
//...
List <String> someList = new ArrayList <String> ();
//...
```

When the compiler hits the word `List`, in the first case, it will need to figure out if `List` exists in that set of classes or not. In the second case, it is already given it explicitly, so its much easier.

In essence, what happens is the compiler must take all the classes existing in the `import` statements and keep track of their names so that, if you use it, the compiler can then retrieve the appropriate functions that you are calling.

Sometimes, there are classes that have the same name in multiple packages. It is in this case (which Thomas is referring to) that you should not use the `*` to select all the classes in the directory.

It is best practice to explicitly describe your class usage.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't impact performance to have excess import statements. It may make the source code longer than it should be but there is no effect on the compiled code. Java itself imports unnecessary class files - see the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html) [section 7.5.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5.5):

> Each compilation unit automatically imports all of the public type
>   names declared in the predefined package java.lang, as if the
>   declaration:
>   `import java.lang.*;`
>   appeared at the beginning of each
>   compilation unit, immediately following any package statement.

[Section 7.5.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5.2) says that

> A type-import-on-demand declaration never causes any other declaration
>   to be shadowed.

...meaning that wildcard imports won't trump single-entry imports.

As others have pointed out, any decent IDE (NetBeans, Eclipse, etc) will remove unused imports for you.

Comment: It doesn't always make the source code longer. `import javax.swing.*;` probably imports a lot of unused classes, but it's a lot shorter than explicitly importing each Swing widget your program uses.

Answer (score 2):

Like many questions about performance, clarity of the code is usually more important.  This should be your first thought, and only in the rare cases where you have a known (measured) performance problem you should consider not writing the simplest and clearest code you can.

Like many performance questions, in this case the simplest, clearest code is also the fastest.

You should maintain your `import` or have your IDE maintain them, to keep them clear and make you code easier to maintain.  The performance issue is very small, even for the compiler or IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest danger is namespace collisions.  If two imported libraries both have a List type for example, it may not use the one you think it is.

Comment: This is incorrect. Let's say you want to import `List` and import both `java.awt.List` and `java.util.List`, the compiler will complain about the 2nd one since you already have a single-type import for `List`. If you import `java.awt.*` and `java.util.*` the compiler will fail due to ambiguous references to `List`. The only way to achieve your scenario is if you import one single-type and one wildcard, e.g. `java.awt.*` and `java.util.List` - the single-type will be favored. See the Java Language Spec [section 7.5.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5.1)

Answer (score 1):

It is important to remove them because they add bloat to the `.java` file and because getting rid of them within a given file is fast and cheap, especially if you're using an IDE (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>, I believe, is the shortcut in Eclipse).

As far as "What do redundant imports do for the machine", well, not much really. The *class* itself will only be added to the relevant `jar` file once, and it will only be loaded once per class (please see not vis-a-vis "per class"), so aside from adding some trivial amount of time to compilation, it won't really have any substantial long-term effect on the program itself.

That said, it is cheap and easy to fix the problem: if you aren't using an IDE, then you should have clearly grouped import statements which are in some sane order to begin with (I alphabetize mine, meaning that I'll immediately see two imports of `java.util.Map`, because they'd be right next to each other!). Your fellow coders will actively complian if you don't fix it, so I suggest that it is in your best interest to do so.

Comment: The class itself will only be loaded once, period, unless the program has custom class loading issues. 'Bloat' in the .java file isn't even accurate in the case of .e.g. `import javax.swing.*`, and in any case it isn't much of a reason to make it 'important to remove them': you haven't given any others.

Comment: @EJP That is not entirely accurate. Because of how the JVM loads classes, it is quite possible that multiple boot-loaders will load the same class multiple times. It is a subtlety which I'll admit I have not fully explained, but it seemed awkward and excessive to do so.

Comment: It is possible that multiple *loaders* will load the class once each, and I specifically provided for such exceptional cases in my comment.